# How to receive Paypal donations (and information) without server-side code?

Tags: javascript, paypal

I am making a website for a school club (a FIRST Robotics team) and we rely heavily on donations. I am looking for a way to display information about donors if they choose to have it displayed. The biggest problem is that the server it is on doesn't work well with most server-side code so I am limited to HTML/CSS, JavaScript and PHP.

The way I have thought of doing this is having a form on the site which would send information they choose (I.E. a name/company) to a google spreadsheet and then somehow have the PayPal payment confirmation be sent to the spreadsheet as well to prevent people from just sending whatever information they want to the spreadsheet.

So: Is it possible to get a PayPal payment confirmation sent to an arbitrary source in a format I specify? If so, how would I go about doing this? If not are there any other ways I can achieve the same result (display donation information on my website without server-side code)?

Comment: Given that your server can run PHP, why isn't PHP a viable server-side choice?

Comment: but PHP = Server side.. Perhaps you meant limited features?

Answer (score 1):

Paypal's buy now buttons don't require any server side code unless you want to know or store if the transaction was successful on the site. Check out this: http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/